How to make deeplink ionic for ios correct?
I was developing a hybrid mobile application for Android/iOS using Nuxt 3, TypeScript, and Ionic. My app serves as an online store. During the payment process, the application redirects users to the epay Halyk website, and when the 'back' button is pressed, it should lead back to our application.
This functionality works well on Android devices and in the Xcode emulator. However, when I build it for TestFlight and the App Store, it doesn't work. I'm not sure why this issue is occurring.
      window.halyk.pay({
            ...response.data,
            backLink:        'https://m.smartdeal.kz',
            failureBackLink: 'https://m.smartdeal.kz',
            postLink:        response.data.postLink,
        });


This sounds like a back button issue, this has nothing to do with deep-linking feature. The docs state how to set it up. https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/hardware-back-button
